# Retrofit 2.0 define variable type

Tags: retrofit2, android, gson

My team using Retrofit 2.0 (I'm not android guy), when I select ID from mysql, it always returns string type, but my project requires to return by Integer. Anyone know how to convert type with Retrofit 2.0.
Thank you so much!

Comment: There is no direct relation between mysql (DB) and retrofit library (REST)

Comment: When defining ID, I use int type and when db returns string type, I get conflict. :D